# Angular "Duplicate key in repeater" error only on one machine - IE Chrome & FF

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, selectlist

I'm not going to post code here because the offending code base is not actually mine and since the problem is only on 1 machine in all three browsers I believe it to be a machine level security/config/install version problem.

I have an AngularJs page with a  control that contains an ng-repeat attribute.

```
<div ng-if="centralObject.OfficerList && centralObject.OfficerList.length > 0" 
     ng-repeat="officer in centralObject.OfficerList" 
     class="officer-form ng-scope">
```

Every instance on the page has the same value for the ng-repeat attribute.

There is a select list in every instance of the repeated `<div>` that lists 7 possible officer titles.

This works on every machine in the world that I can tell except for 1. On that machine the Chrome Console window throws a **Duplicate key in Repeater** error and complains about the Officer List.

The select list on that machine has 311 options with values 1 through 311 all with empty labels.

This happens on all three major browsers on this machine which is why I didn't bother posting the source. It seems like a security setting or some other machine level issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Not clear with your problem statement, however, in your ng-repeat, you can try to add `track by $index` or some unique field and check

Comment: The problem is that on one machine I get a angularjs duplicate key in repeater error in every browser and I don't on 6 other machines. The ones that work have a select with 7 options, the one that errors has a select with 311 options with no labels.

Comment: not enough code

Comment: Key point here is: **What is contained in `centralObject.OfficerList`?**

Comment: it's hard to say what is the root cause. reason - most probable - is your `officeList` is list of primitives(strings?) and there are duplicates. maybe - just maybe - at that machine there are some crazy firewall installed that drops just single request. And because of that you are getting list with `undefined` instead of real values. Anyway it's easier for you to debug.

Comment: *I'm not going to post code here because...* << **Wrong!** https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. And move that `ng-if` out of the `ng-repeat`. Please.

Answer (score 1):

Please post a plunker or fiddle link with proper information. 
You can try track by $index or track by someuniqueProperty

```
<div ng-if="centralObject.OfficerList && centralObject.OfficerList.length > 0" ng-repeat="officer in centralObject.OfficerList track by $index" class="officer-form ng-scope">
```

or

```
<div ng-if="centralObject.OfficerList && centralObject.OfficerList.length > 0" ng-repeat="officer in centralObject.OfficerList track by officer.uniqueId" class="officer-form ng-scope">
```

uniqueId being some property that holds unique values for every officer. Hope this helps